# How do you select data from MySQL database for it to be used in Combo Box Selection?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, combobox

So usually when you create a combo box you'll be the one to put the value of the selection but I want the data in my combo box will be selected from my database mysql. How am I going to do that?

I am stuck at selecting data from my sql to combo box!

Here's my code so far!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection connection = null;            
            string hostname = "localhost";
            string database = "aparece_hoteldb";
            string username = "root";
            string password = "";
            connection = new MySqlConnection("host=" + hostname + 
                                            ";database=" + database + 
                                            ";username=" + username + 
                                            ";password=" + password + ";");


            string table = "reservations";
            string query = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
            connection.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter da_res = null;
            DataSet ds_res = null;
            ds_res = new DataSet();
            da_res = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
            da_res.Fill(ds_res, table);

            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds_res.Tables[table];

        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the `reservations` table data in a combo box? Because right now you're binding that information to the data grid. Is there another table you're trying to fill the combo box with? And if so, what's the structure of that table?

Comment: yes I have another panel for combo box separately from datagrid!

Comment: what i want is just to get the data from my mysql to be used in combo box

Comment: Is the combo box in the data grid row or is it separate from it?

Comment: Hey Michael i dunno what you mean but is it possible to put combo box in datagrid? But to your question yes it is separate from datagrid.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so binding a list of data to a combo box, especially when it's one you've already got, is going to be pretty straight forward. So, after this line:

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = ds_res.Tables[table];
```

let's add a few more:

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "YourDisplayField";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "YourValueField";
comboBox1.DataSource = ds_res.Tables[table];
```

and that will bind the data to the combo box. But let's break this down. The `DisplayMember` is the field value that you want the user to see. Often times this is a name or a brief description of the row. The `ValueMember` is the field you want bound to the `SelectedValue` property. When the user selects an item in the combo box the `SelectedValue` will be set to the value of that field.

Now you can consume a better event that `SelectedIndexChanged`, now you can consume [`SelectedValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged.aspx). Every time the user selects a new value that event will fire and you can do with it what you need.

You could get the actual `DataRow` if you wanted by casting the `SelectedItem` property of the combo box like this:

```
var row = comboBox1.SelectedItem as DataRow;
```

or you could just grab that value and do something with it:

```
var val = comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

and you could cast that to whatever type the `ValueMember` field is. If you set it to an `int` field then you might do something like this:

```
var val = (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

if it's a `string` field then maybe something like this:

```
var val = comboBox1.SelectedValue as string;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get a single column returned by your sql you could set the datasource of the combobox to populate it from the datatable or dataset.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

Comment: hmmmmm Ok then how am i suppose to do that?

Comment: yes you are right i want to get the data from a single column but i dunno, what is the code for that?

Comment: well, anyway if i can't make it working i will go back to php programming language which is i'm comfortable working with. Actually this is our project "hotel reservation" any prog. language will do prof said.

Comment: All you need to do is return a single column dataset and set it equal to the DataSource. 
    SELECT mycolumn FROM myTable.

Answer (score 0):

//inside the FORM_LOAD,

```
private void Form7_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        cboFloor.SelectedIndex = -1;
        cboFloor.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        GetFloor();
        }
```

//Create a Function and insert this code.

```
private voide GetFloor{
        string query = @"SELECT DISTINCT floor FROM tbroom ORDER BY floor ASC";



        try
        {
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
            MySqlDataReader rdr;
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                cboFloor.Items.Add(rdr["floor"]);

            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException mysqlex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mysqlex.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }}
```